# My code isn't printing any of the while loop when I give it valid input. How do I fix?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, nested-loops

Trying to run:

```
pin = int(input('Enter your PIN: '))

while pin != 1234:
  pin = int(input('Incorrect PIN. Enter your PIN again: '))
  
  if pin == 1234:
    print('PIN accepted!')
```

It just lets me input a code in the console but then doesn't show any sort of output response if I input 1234. If I input the wrong code it does run the *while pin* loop. How do I get it to run the *if pin* statment?

I've tried to switch the code around, but I get alot of errors if I do that. Tried restarting visula studio, but that didn't work either. I know the answer has gotta be simple but I don't know enough to find it on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `if` statement outside of the `while` loop.

```
pin = int(input('Enter your PIN: '))

while pin != 1234:
  pin = int(input('Incorrect PIN. Enter your PIN again: '))

if pin == 1234:
  print('PIN accepted!')
```

The issue is that it only enters the `while` loop if the pin **is not** 1234.